# UITextField give suggetion when typing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Like In Google we write "ahe" it will show suggestion Like below screenshot. How it will possible in my iPhone UITextField when we typing???[image]

Comment: this one might help you. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview

Comment: Yes you will have to UISearchBar for this and use an external API for the search options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try this :

https://github.com/keyf/AutocompletionTableView/downloads

and this also-

Simplest way to do is to make a method and connect it with UiTextfield with event UIControlEventEditingChanged which will give you the trace on every character entered in the textfield.

```
[self.selectedTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(enterInLabel ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


-(void)enterInLabel 
{ 
selectedLabel.text=selectedTextField.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add self delegate method which will call when any change in yourTextField.

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


- (void)textFieldDidChange
{
    //you may need to call [resultArray removeAllObjects] to get fresh list of cities here.
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"City like[cd] %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", yourTextField.text]];
    resultArray = [[cityArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
}
```

P.S. here, `cityArray` contains list of city, and `resultArray` returns filtered cities list of type `NSMutableArray`. Also, in `NSPredicate` City is a field on which I am performing search operation.